# AWS Lambda Alias in Role Policy

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

Is there a way to design a Lambda execution role policy to restrict access by using Lambda alias name. For example, I want to have an alias "Prod" and only executions of function with that alias would have permissions to write to a particular bucket.

I tried using the new lambda:SourceFunctionArn condition, but it does not seem to include the alias, or I am not using it correctly. In the example below I am trying to achieve ability of all variants of my function to write into my-bucket-test, but only Prod alias to be able to write to my-bucket-data. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Sid": "Logging",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/MyLambda_*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-test/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3Prod",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-data/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "lambda:SourceFunctionArn": "*Prod"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks,
Alex